# Xcode 5 iPhone app on iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I've installed Xcode 5 alongside Xcode 4 so I can build for both iOS6 and 7 SDKs.

I have a working iPhone App that, when I load it in Xcode 4 and build it to run on the iPad simulator it shows up with the 1x/2x button in the bottom right corner of the screen indicating that this is an iPhone App installed on an iPad.

When I do the same thing in Xcode 5, however, it appears that it isn't installing it on the iOS7 iPad simulator as an iPhone app because I don't see the 1x/2x button in the corner, and things are laid out slightly differently.

Again, this is the exact same Xcode project (actually it's a workspace) opened in Xcode 4 and built for an iPad simulator and opened in Xcode 5 and build for an iPad simulator.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to get an iPhone app to run as such on an iOS7 iPad simulator? Or why this might be happening?

Comment: Use the retina iPad Simulator (and scale it to 50%). I don't have a non retina iPad at hand so I can't test it, but on iPad 3rd Gen and Retina Simulator the button appears.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 uses the iPhone's retina artwork and so always appears in x2 format.